# Filter an array with boolean array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two lists:

```
let cities = ["Istanbul", "Ankara", "Izmir"];
let filterVals = [true, false, false];
```

I need to filter cities using filterVals array.

In the example, I'm expecting only "Istanbul" for example.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Maybe this is what you need? `cities.filter((item, index) => filterVals[index])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as easy as a simple one-liner:

```js
cities.filter((city, index) => filterVals[index])
```

```js
const cities = ["Istanbul", "Ankara", "Izmir"];
const filterVals = [true, false, false];

const result = cities.filter((city, index) => filterVals[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```js
let cities = ["Istanbul", "Ankara", "Izmir"];
let filterVals = [true, false, false];


const newCities = cities.filter((city, index) => filterVals[index]);

console.log(newCities);
```